# How to always have a valid (fresh) token on googleAPIs

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-oauth, google-calendar-api

Currently using googleapis for my projects https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client

I'm working on an app, Where user can connect their G-Calendar account.

Using google.auth.OAuth2 I can receive access and refresh token.
And I can get a fresh access_token using refresh token.

My question is, since user not always using the app.
And we don't want to make user authenticate everytime needed.

1. What should be the strategy to always have the fresh token.
   running cron to always refresh the token? or only request when user using it ?
2. related to first question, what if the refresh token itself expires. Since when requesting new refresh token, we only get a new access_token (not refresh token itself)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I apologize in advance if my answer seems irrelevant or incomplete, since I'm not quite sure on how the code works I am taking some assumptions.

I believe that a tradeoff where you would sacrifice security for convenience would be needed in this scenario as [API Keys](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys) should allow you to keep the access to the account but this is the most exploitable method of authentication, it also requires some setup on the user's side as they will need to:

- Create a project
- Create a service account
- Create an API Key
- Share the API key with you

The good news is that an API key will remain active.

Hope it helps!